# Does Grunt Watch trigger only when Terminal Open?

Tags: gruntjs, watch

This may be a dumb question but does grunt-contrib-watch Watch command only trigger while the terminal is open? Will my grunt commands still trigger if I close the Terminal?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It triggers as long as the grunt process is running. Unless you run it in the background, no, it will not trigger after you close the terminal window.